# In Unity apply filter to Image/Texture2D and assign it to plane

Tags: image-processing, unity-game-engine

I trying to implement image filter for texture2d which is uploaded by user at run-time and assign it to Unity plane. i know by using .GetPixel and .SetPixel we can perform but i don't know it is a proper way or not.

how can i achieve this in proper way?
Is there any way to use GPU for boosting performance?
Can you provide me some example/tutorial_links to getting start (filter, image processing/editing in unity).

I like to know by using unity shader can we process the image and get the final image as texture2D then use it as we want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, you can always use custom shaders to do all kinds of effects. Please read more about shaders in unity here https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/gentle-introduction-shaders   https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Shaders.html. You can also use image post process to achieve even more https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html

Comment: More information https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/graphics/image-effects-overview

Comment: I like to process the texture2d variable and save it to my server